# Move topMenu to content area magento

Tags: xml, magento, block

I created a new custom block in magento XML:

```
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="menu" template="page/html/menu.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

The block shows however i am not capable to show the catalog/navigation/top.phtml, i included this code within the custom block:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
```

However the menu is not showing? What am I missing? Many Thanx for any assistance!

Comment: Want you show topMenu (and its template /catalog/navigation/top.phtml) inside the custom menu block (page/html/menu.phtml)?

Comment: Yes indeed! The topmenu inside the custom block. However with the php tag. I managed to put it in there with xml but i need some container divs as wel for css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try show block with code (menu.phtml):

`echo $this->getParentBlock()->getParentBlock()->getChildHtml('header')->getChildHtml('topMenu');`

Or `echo $this->getParentBlock()->getParentBlock()->getChildHtml('topMenu');`

I tried it (but with another files) and it works!